# How do I add a parameter to OnChangeEventHandler

Tags: c#, sql-server, event-handling, sqldependency

I need to set up different SqlDependencies for different "symbol" rows being insert into DB.

How can I pass Symbol in the OnChangeEventHandler set-up?

```
public void SetDepedencyForSymbol(string symbol)
{
    string cmdText = "SELECT [Symbol] FROM [" + AccountCode + "].[FilledOrders] WHERE [Symbol] = '" + symbol + "'";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
    {

        SqlDependency FilledDependency = new SqlDependency(command);
        FilledDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyForFillsChange);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Process the DataReader.
        }
    }
}

void OnDependencyForFillsChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).

    // How can I get value of "symbol" here
}
```

Comment: You desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This code is wide open to sql injection. As for the question at hand, I don't understand what you are trying to do. You have some code just floating out in space but the rest of it is in a method.

Comment: @SeanLange I edited question to put it in a method. I want to know which "Symbol" was used to set-up the dependency when I get to OnDependencyForFillsChange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the signature of an event handler. A handler for the `OnChange` event of a `SqlDependency` will always accept an `object` and a `SqlNotificationEventArgs` and you cannot change this.

You could use an anonymous delegate to handle the event though. Then you will be able to access the symbol parameter:

```
public void SetDepedencyForSymbol(string symbol)
{
    string cmdText = "SELECT [Symbol] FROM [" + AccountCode + "].[FilledOrders] WHERE [Symbol] = '" + symbol + "'";

    OnChangeEventHandler handler = (sender, args) =>
    {
        string theSymbol = symbol;
        // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).

    };
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
    {

        SqlDependency FilledDependency = new SqlDependency(command);
        FilledDependency.OnChange += handler;

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Process the DataReader.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is just what I wanted.